# Wrapping an ActiveRecord object as a PORO. How do get all the attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to wrap an AR object as a PORO as part of an API response for the purpose of preventing the client application from calling `.save` on the object. However, I want all the attributes and this object has like 50 columns. Is there an easy way to create `attr_accessors` for all of the attributes?

Say this is the beginning of my class:

```
module Something
    class Apple

      attr_accessor [...]
```

Say the AR model is also called Apple.

What goes inside there? Is there a way for me to quickly get all the attributes of the AR Apple as attr_accessors?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother. It'd be simpler to use the `readonly` active record method.

[docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#readonly-objects)

```
Apple.readonly.first
Apple.readonly.where(display: true)
```